# Managing multiple helm subcharts as part of Continuous Integration

Tags: docker, kubernetes, continuous-integration, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

My current situation is that there are multiple APIs and frontends as part of one package. Currently, the CI pipeline builds the docker container and pushes it to a repository, tagged with the build number.

I am currently trying to produce a Helm chart as part of each build.
When packaging the chart, I can use "helm package --app-version XXXX" to use the build number for this chart but I don't know how I'd change the value of the tag to use based on the build number.

My end goal is to have a separate repository which contains just a Helm chart to encompass the subcharts with the build numbers of each of the components and release that as a specific version. So the main chart would be 1.0.0 and the subcharts would be versioned based on their builds.

My questions are:
1. Is it possible to change the values in a chart before publishing it? If so, how would I go about doing it?
2. Does this approach sound good for CI/CD and a Microservice style architecture?

Thanks,
James

Comment: `Is it possible to change the values in a chart before publishing it` you mean override the values of `sub-chart-1` in `main-chart` ?

Comment: I mean when packaging a sub-chart to change some of the values. I can do it with Powershell but would prefer to do it in a less hacky way.

Comment: @JamesB. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: In the end, we went with just deploying each individually and updating when needed manually. Doing it in the way I asked the question would mean that the whole chart would need to be re-packaged for each change in each sub-chart anyway so doesn't really make sense anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the values when packing a chart or subchart with the `--set` flag, even when you do a `helm update` [check out this section](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#customizing-the-chart-before-installing)